# How we can add Name of a restful response result List

Tags: json, spring, web-services, response

I have a service which is producing List of results I want to give the name of each list,find the Example.

Current Result:

```
[
[
    {
        "marketname": "East",
        "totalmarketcount": 22
    },
    {
        "marketname": "Midwest",
        "totalmarketcount": 9275
    },
    {
        "marketname": "West",
        "totalmarketcount": 25
    }
],
[
    {
        "discarded": 0,
        "received": 1268,
        "coded": 6031,
        "completed": 5951
    }
],
```

But I want :

```
 {
"EncoderCodedlist": [
    {
        "totalcount": 6001,
        "encountercoder": "name1"
    },
    {
        "totalcount": 41,
        "encountercoder": "name8"
    },
    {
        "totalcount": 6,
        "encountercoder": "name6"
    },
    {
        "totalcount": 3,
        "encountercoder": "name4"
    },
    {
        "totalcount": 3,
        "encountercoder": "name2"
    }
]
```

}

I am using Spring Boot and Spring rest, which we produce the json object.

Comment: you have to change your pojo / model calss. show the model class, we can suggest how to change

Comment: create a JSON object and name it as you like example "totalNumberOfCount" and then insert the JSON array to it.

Comment: The code snippet you want to output is invalid JSON.

Comment: @pvpkiran for this response multiple POJO I created.

Comment: Map<String,List> map =new HashMap<>();
  
   map.put("MarketDetailsList", (List) lists.get(0));
   map.put("totalnumberofCount", (List) lists.get(1));
I did this way as of now , please suggest me if any issue will occur.

Comment: check the format you are asking for. It is not a valid json.

Comment: @– pvpkiran  sorry I need this {
    "EncoderCodedlist": [
        {
            "totalcount": 6001,
            "encountercoder": "name1"
        },
        {
            "totalcount": 41,
            "encountercoder": "name8"
        },
        {
            "totalcount": 6,
            "encountercoder": "name6"
        },
        {
            "totalcount": 3,
            "encountercoder": "name4"
        },
        {
            "totalcount": 3,
            "encountercoder": "name2"
        }
    ]
}